# What is the leaf venation of a scuppernong vine leaf?

Tags: botany

I googled around and I didn't find anything that says its leaf veination. Anyone know?

Comment: 2 hours later...;-; Does no one know?

Comment: Check [this](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/grape-vines-parallel-veins-netted-veins-104247.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link, it's netted veination, though it doesn't say if it's palmate or pinnate. So I relied on using my own judgement on looking at my scuppernong leaf and it looks decidedly palmate. It would be better if I had confirmation from some site or such, but as it has main veins and smaller veins sprouting from those main veins, I think it's palmate.

Additionally, for all other botany question confusion, I finally found this website which may be useful: http://rampages.us/fieldbotany/2014/05/23/grape-vine-3/